# Evaluate the flux $\mathbf{F} = (-x, -y, z)$ across the surface $S$ that is the part of the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, geometry, spherical-coordinates, surface-integrals

**Problem**

Evaluate the flux $\mathbf{F} = (-x, -y, z)$ across the surface $S$ that is the part of the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ that lies between the planes $z = 1$ and $z = 2$ and has inward orientation. Use spherical coordinates.

---

I've graphed the cone and the two planes intersecting through it. I know how to calculate flux using the correct orientation, and I know spherical coordinates. What I can't figure out is how to find the limits of integration using spherical coordinates. For instance, I know that $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ for this problem, but how do I find $\rho$ and $\phi$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please explain how to find the limits of integration in spherical coordinates for this problem after having graphed the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion from Cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates is:

$$\begin{align}{ \rho = \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}
\\ \theta = \arctan{\frac{y}{x}}
\\ \phi = \arccos{\frac{z}{\rho}}}\end{align}$$

You've already ascertained that $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ by rotational symmetry, but you can use the equation of the cone to work out the integration limits of $\rho$ and $\phi$ by expressing them in terms of $z$. Answer below.

> $\rho = \sqrt{z^{2}+z^{2}} = \sqrt{2}z \,;\;\phi = \arccos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} = \pi/4$. So $\rho \in [\sqrt{2},2\sqrt{2}]$, and as $\phi$ is constant you wouldn't even integrate over it (which makes sense, since you're integrating over a surface, so there should only be two integration variables, which here are $\rho$ and $\theta$).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am confused; $\phi = \arccos{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} = \pi/4$? How did you get $\pi/2$?

Comment: Yep, I messed up. Corrected, thanks!